# Detach a process from Sh (not Bash) or “disown” for Sh (not Bash)

Tags: shell, process-management, disown

Consider a shell script executed by Sh, not Bash (and I can't change it, and can't use a shebang, it's ignored). The `&` operator works, but `disown $!` does not and makes Sh complains “*disown: not found*”.

How do I detach a background process from specifically Sh? I mean, doing from Sh the same as `disown` do from Bash.

Comment: In scripts, `disown` has no effect anyway (is not needed)

Comment: How no effect? You mean the shell session which launched the background process will close and let the background process continue? You mean I don't need `disown` or similar at all?

Comment: Yes, try `sh -c 'sleep 100 &'` and see that `sleep` is still running after `sh` has returned (`sh -c` is to run _inline scripts_).

Comment: I checked it, indeed, it's as you say. So that's strange I had issues with this in the past, and that's due to these issues I wanted to use `disown` now. I will leave this question open for now and will either complete it or close it, depending on further future cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let's see what Bash's `disown` command does. From [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals):

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`. Before exiting, an interactive shell resends the `SIGHUP` to all jobs, running or stopped. Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the `SIGHUP`. To prevent the shell from sending the `SIGHUP` signal to a particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin (see Job Control Builtins) or marked to not receive `SIGHUP` using `disown -h`.
>
> If the `huponexit` shell option has been set with `shopt` (see The Shopt Builtin), Bash sends a `SIGHUP` to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits.

What this means is that it's the shell itself, if it receives `SIGHUP`, forwards it to the background jobs. If the shell exits (and `huponexit` had't been enabled), the background processes—which don't have a controlling terminal—don't get `SIGHUP` on terminal closing.

So if your concern is to prevent `SIGHUP` to a process launched from a shell wrapper, like e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
my-command arg &
```

then there's no need in `disown`-like functionality, since `my-command` will not receive `SIGHUP` unless the shell gets it before exiting.

But, there still is a problem if you want to run a child from a script that will continue execution for some time after launching the child, like e.g. here:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 55555 &
sleep 3333 # some long operation we don't care about
```

The script above will terminate the `sleep 55555` command if the script's controlling terminal closes. Since Bourne shell doesn't have the `disown` builtin that Bash, Ksh and some other shells have, we need another tool. That tool is [`nohup(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup). The above script, in which we aren't interested in the `stdout` and `stderr` of the child process, can be modified to the following to avoid `sleep` getting `SIGHUP`:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup sleep 55555 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 3333 # some long operation we don't care about
```

The redirection to `/dev/null` is to avoid getting the `nohup.out` file in current directory. Without the redirection, this file will contain the output of the nohupped process.

Comment: so we can delete the file with `rm nohup.out` if we still want standard out and error from our commands