# How to disown a command in the busybox shell?

Tags: background-process, busybox, disown

I'm trying to write a quick-and-dirty shell script daemon to run on a home router that has a busybox shell, which doesn't support `disown`. Is there any way to do either of the following?

- Run a command like `command &` and then disown it once it's in the background.
- Run a command "directly" in the background (i.e., not using `&`).

Comment: Very similar, if not a dupe of this: [Detach a process from Sh (not Bash) or “disown” for Sh (not Bash)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147760)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're the one writing a quick and dirty daemon: let it fork off into the background and let the starting process exit immediately after forking, like any other daemon might.

Comment: The issue is that the daemon itself is a script, so if I can't disown a process from the shell, then neither can the script.

Comment: @joshlf please **edit** your question to include that crucial piece of information! A shell script is usually not what people consider a daemon, so that's why I'm a bit surprised :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an X Y problem.

Busybox is a very primitive shell, it doesn't support disown.

But why do you want to disown anyway?  It's already in the background, and if you exit the shell, busybox isn't going to kill it.  The only point of disown is to remove the process from the shell's list of things it is monitoring.